# Proper table to track employee changes over time?

Tags: postgresql

I have been using Python to do this in memory, but I would like to know the proper way to set up an employee mapping table in Postgres.

```
row_id | employee_id | other_id | other_dimensions | effective_date | expiration_date | is_current
```

- Unique constraint on (employee_id, other_id), so a new row would be inserted whenever there is a change
- I would want the expiration date from the previous row to be updated to the new effective_date minus 1 day, and the is_current should be updated to False
- Ultimate purpose is to be able to map each employee back accurately on a given date

Would love to hear some best practices so I can move away from my file-based method where I read the whole roster into memory and use pandas to make changes, then truncate the original table and insert the new one.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by "other_id" and "other_dimensions". Could you clarify your intent a bit?

Comment: That could be literally anything which might change. For example, a manager or a location. In my specific case, it includes IDs for other systems which are not incorporated into our employee management system. We need to track these IDs (from various custom tools, telephony systems, Salesforce, etc) back to the official employee ID, but some of them are recycled or get changed.

Comment: Best practices would be to use stored procedures to still perform your operation atomically. I'll have to think a bit though to phrase it as an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general example built using the column names you provided that I think does more or less what you want. Don't treat it as a literal ready-to-run solution, but rather an example of how to make something like this work that you'll have to modify a bit for your own actual use case.

The rough idea is to make an underlying raw table that holds all your data, and establish a view on top of this that gets used for ordinary access. You can still use the raw table to do anything you need to do to or with the data, no matter how complicated, but the view provides more restrictive access for regular use. Rules are put in place on the view to enforce these restrictions and perform the special operations you want. While it doesn't sound like it's significant for your current application, it's important to note that these restrictions can be enforced via PostgreSQL's roles and privileges and the SQL `GRANT` command.

We start by making the raw table. Since the `is_current` column is likely to be used for reference a lot, we'll put an index on it. We'll take advantage of PostgreSQL's `SERIAL` type to manage our raw table's `row_id` for us. The view doesn't even need to reference the underlying `row_id`. We'll default the `is_current` to a `True` value as we expect most of the time we'll be adding current records, not past ones.

```
CREATE TABLE raw_employee (
  row_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  employee_id INTEGER,
  other_id INTEGER,
  other_dimensions VARCHAR,
  effective_date DATE,
  expiration_date DATE,
  is_current BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE
);

CREATE INDEX employee_is_current_index ON raw_employee (is_current);
```

Now we define our view. To most of the world this will be the normal way to access employee data. Internally it's a special `SELECT` run on-demand against the underlying `raw_employee` table that we've already defined. If we had reason to, we could further refine this view to hide more data (it's already hiding the low-level `row_id` as mentioned earlier) or display additional data produced either via calculation or relations with other tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW employee AS 
 SELECT employee_id, other_id,
     other_dimensions, effective_date, expiration_date,
     is_current
   FROM raw_employee;
```

Now our rules. We construct these so that whenever someone tries an operation against our view, internally it'll perform a operation against our raw table according to the restrictions we define. First `INSERT`; it mostly just passes the data through without change, but it has to account for the hidden `row_id`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE employee_insert AS ON INSERT TO employee DO INSTEAD
  INSERT INTO raw_employee VALUES (
    NEXTVAL('raw_employee_row_id_seq'),
    NEW.employee_id, NEW.other_id,
    NEW.other_dimensions,
    NEW.effective_date, NEW.expiration_date,
    NEW.is_current
  );
```

The `NEXTVAL` part enables us to lean on PostgreSQL for `row_id` handling. Next is our most complicated one: `UPDATE`. Per your described intent, it has to match against `employee_id`, `other_id` pairs and perform two operations: updating the old record to be no longer current, and inserting a new record with updated dates. You didn't specify how you wanted to manage new expiration dates, so I took a guess. It's easy to change it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE employee_update AS ON UPDATE TO employee DO INSTEAD (
  UPDATE raw_employee SET is_current = FALSE
    WHERE raw_employee.employee_id = OLD.employee_id AND
      raw_employee.other_id = OLD.other_id;
  INSERT INTO raw_employee VALUES (
    NEXTVAL('raw_employee_row_id_seq'),
    COALESCE(NEW.employee_id, OLD.employee_id),
    COALESCE(NEW.other_id, OLD.other_id),
    COALESCE(NEW.other_dimensions, OLD.other_dimensions),
    COALESCE(NEW.effective_date, OLD.expiration_date - '1 day'::INTERVAL),
    COALESCE(NEW.expiration_date, OLD.expiration_date + '1 year'::INTERVAL),
    TRUE
  );
);
```

The use of `COALESCE` enables us to update columns that have explicit updates, but keep old values for ones that don't. Finally, we need to make a rule for `DELETE`. Since you said you want to ensure you can track employee histories, the best way to do this is also the simplest: we just disable it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE employee_delete_protect AS
    ON DELETE TO employee DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

Now we ought to be able to insert data into our raw table by performing `INSERT` operations on our view. Here are two sample employees; the first has a few weeks left but the second is about to expire. Note that at this level we don't need to care about the `row_id`. It's an internal implementation detail of the lower level raw table.

```
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (
  1, 1,
  'test', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 week', CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '3 weeks',
  TRUE
);

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (
  2, 2,
  'another test', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 month', CURRENT_DATE,
  TRUE
);
```

The final example is deceptively simple after all the build-up that we've done. It performs an `UPDATE` operation on the view, and internally it results in an update to the existing employee #2 plus a new entry for employee #2.

```
UPDATE employee SET expiration_date = CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 year'
  WHERE employee_id = 2 AND other_id = 2;
```

Again I'll stress that this isn't meant to just take and use without modification. There should be enough info here though for you to make something work for your specific case.

Comment: Yes, very cool and helpful. I'll use this as a reference and test it. Thanks!